# Configure FTP-Proxy in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

my update site is only via ftp reachable and the customer needs to set a proxy. But i can't select a FTP-Proxy in the preference page (General -> Network Connections). How can i add the ftp schema? There are no buttons like 'add proxy'

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 'Active Provider' on top of the General -> Network Connections page to 'Manual' - you will then be able to edit individual proxy schemas.